# Cannot Directly Launch App which Defines and Enforces Custom Permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

I've recently started learning Android Development.

I have made two apps: *PermissionsApp* and *DangerousApp*.
The latter (DangerousApp) defines its own permission in the manifest file as follows:

```
<permission
    android:name="course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous"
    android:label="Dangerous Activity" />
```

It also self-enforces this permission in the activity tag:

```
<application
    android:permission="course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM"
    ...>
```

The former (PermissionsApp) uses it in its own manifest files as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM"/>
```

The *PermissionsApp* is hence able to launch *DangerousApp* from within itself. However, I am **unable to directly launch** the *DangerousApp* from the list of applications (launcher?). The LogCat shows there is a security exception thrown whereby the launcher didn't have permission.

Any explanations on why this is the case?

Comment: "However, I am unable to directly launch the DangerousApp from the list of applications (launcher?)." Isn't that one of the reasons to declare and require this permission?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: Yes, I understand now. I had mistakenly thought that starting any app's main activity "directly" i.e. via a launcher was somehow immune to any permission requirements as the permissions only applied to 'other apps'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I am unable to directly launch the DangerousApp from the list of applications (launcher?).

Correct.

> Any explanations on why this is the case?

The home screen does not have a `<uses-permission>` element for `course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM`. You have stated that every component in your application is defended by that permission, which will include your launcher activity.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. But how do I force other apps to require permission to launch my DangerousApp but not the launcher? I feel I am missing something very trivial here.

Comment: @Abhi: "But how do I force other apps to require permission to launch my DangerousApp but not the launcher?" -- I do not know what "launch my DangerousApp" means. You are welcome to put the `android:permission` attribute on individual components of your app, instead of having it on the `<application>` element. So, for example, suppose you have two activities: the launcher activity and another activity. If you move `android:permission` to the `<activity>` for the other activity, the permission will no longer be required for the launcher activity.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, seems logical.
My *DangerousApp* only has a single "Hello World!"-type activity for now. Am I then correct in my understanding that there is no way to prevent this activity from being launched by some other app which does not have the custom permission without also preventing Launcher from starting this activity? Sorry if this sounds convoluted.

Comment: @Abhi: Your understanding is correct. The home screen is just another app. There are hundreds of home screen implementations, both pre-installed and downloadable from the Play Store.

Comment: And why can I launch an app like that from AVD? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @CommonsWare I got a simple example in which: (1) when I deploy it in real device, it does not run (and I see the expected exception in the log). And if I try to directly launch the app installed, it does not work either. (2) But when I deploy it from a AVD, it opens! Then, if I close it and click on the launcher icon, no longer opens. Same API (22). https://github.com/colares/coursera-android/tree/master/Examples/PermissionExampleBoom

Comment: @colares: What does "when I deploy it from a AVD" mean?

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry for this typo. I mean, deploy it TO an AVD. "Run... > Choose Device > Launch emulator".

Comment: @colares: AFAIK, that bypasses these normal permission checks, as it is not being really "run" by the user, but by debugging tools.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80711/discussion-between-colares-and-commonsware).